# Create Custom List using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to create a List of a custom type with properties of type int, int

```
public class CustomClass
{
   public int EmployeeID{get;set;}
   public int ClientID{get;set;}
}
```

Two parameters that i have to create the list is List and int

My method is

```
CreateCustomClassList(List<int> EmployeeIDList, int clientID}
{
List<CustomClass> lst=new List<CustomClass>();
EmployeeIDList.ForEach
  (u=>lst.Add(new CustomClass
  {
     ClientID=clientID, 
     EmployeeID=u
  });
}
```

I don't want to run a Loop to do this, is there any more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Your `CustomClass` has only private members. Is that intentional? Also your method has no return type?

Comment: @MarkByers   No thats a mistake, i've updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `ToList` here:

```
List<CustomClass> lst = EmployeeIDList
     .Select(employeeID => new CustomClass
     {
         ClientID = clientID, 
         EmployeeID = employeeID
     })
     .ToList();
```

It probably won't be more efficient, but it will be clearer - which in my opinion is more important.

If you *really* want efficiency then your best bet is probably the solution that you have already seem to have rejected - a simple loop:

```
List<CustomClass> lst = new List<CustomClass>(EmployeeIDList.Count);
foreach (int employeeID in EmployeeIDList) {
    lst.Add(new CustomClass
        {
            ClientID = clientID, 
            EmployeeID = employeeID
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, Are you suggesting that a 'for loop' is efficient that a 'select'

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your valuable comment